# Could not get post ID from wp_insert_post()

Tags: wp-insert-post

```
function cgp_create_post($title, $name){
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_type'     => 'custom-post-type',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );

    $mypost_id = post_exists( $title );
    if (!$mypost_id) {
        $mypost_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post, true );
    }
    echo $mypost_id; //this was never echoed and the script abruptly stops here
    update_post_meta( $mypost_id, 'times', '1' );
}
```

Above snippets of my code, result is the custom post is created but the line when i test value of $mypost_id by echoing it, it never echoed anything, the script also abruptly stop at that line.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is nothing wrong with my script above. There is actually a conflict with another plugin which called the same 3rd party script twice via add_action( 'save_post', 'function_name'). This double fired the 3rd party script and caused error when my script above try to do insert post.

I have turned on debug at wp-config.php by setting
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

and then solved the bugs via the error logs provided.